# Retrieve All Documents stored in Alfresco to a single file

Tags: alfresco

I have to export all the Alfresco content to single file or a zip so that all the documents stored in Alfresco can be retrieved easily as per the folder structures and correct file names.
The data is stored in alf_data folder which is of no use to external processes.

Comment: did you try something please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

alf_data directory is not meant to be accessed directly.

By going further I am trying to guess your needs and depending what you have to do, you have these options:

1. From share select the relevant folder and choose 'download as zip'
2. Build a little Alfresco browser navigator, you can easily do this with CMIS and [Browser Binding](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/cmis-1.1-browser-binding.html)
3. Mount Alfresco to be seen as a local folder with Samba, CIFS or WebDAV depending on your OS. For this you need to be careful with network settings and security.

For all of them there's plenty of documentation on the net.

**UPDATE**

The best solution depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If the repository is not huge, and you need to do this only once, like a batch, a remediation activity then download the folder or the documents from share to local using the 'download as zip' option and do what you need to do.

If you don't have access to 'share' and have some developer who can works for you, and you need browsing capability then you can quickly build a javascriptweb interface trough CMIS which is basically a kind of web service, there's some built in service in Alfresco which you can use.

If an external system like a server, needs to have access to Alfresco folder as it would be a local folder, then you can map any Alfresco folder as any network storage. It is quick to setup, provide you have access to the network or ask to modification of firewall rules. Compared to option 1 the advantage is that you don't have a local copy.

Comment: witch solution is the best for you (based on your opinion) ?!? if you can tell me why ?!?